# sshpass not functioning in alpine linux

Tags: docker, ansible, alpine-linux, sshpass

When I install sshpass on alpine linux it will install and the doc will show up if you run it without arguments, but using any argument (valid or invalid) returns `sshpass: Failed to run command: No such file or directory`.

It's pathed and even when using an absolute path it has the same behavior. I want to use this with ansible, but it won't even work directly.

I can't seem to find any information online about this functioning or not functioning for other people, but I used other people's containers and my own and I couldn't get it to function on either.
https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.3/main/x86/sshpass

```
$ docker run -it --rm williamyeh/ansible:alpine3 ash
/ # sshpass
Usage: sshpass [-f|-d|-p|-e] [-hV] command parameters
   -f filename   Take password to use from file
   -d number     Use number as file descriptor for getting password
   -p password   Provide password as argument (security unwise)
   -e            Password is passed as env-var "SSHPASS"
   With no parameters - password will be taken from stdin

   -P prompt     Which string should sshpass search for to detect a password prompt
   -v            Be verbose about what you're doing
   -h            Show help (this screen)
   -V            Print version information
At most one of -f, -d, -p or -e should be used
/ # sshpass hi
sshpass: Failed to run command: No such file or directory
/ # which sshpass
/usr/bin/sshpass
/ # /usr/bin/sshpass
Usage: sshpass [-f|-d|-p|-e] [-hV] command parameters
   -f filename   Take password to use from file
   -d number     Use number as file descriptor for getting password
   -p password   Provide password as argument (security unwise)
   -e            Password is passed as env-var "SSHPASS"
   With no parameters - password will be taken from stdin

   -P prompt     Which string should sshpass search for to detect a password prompt
   -v            Be verbose about what you're doing
   -h            Show help (this screen)
   -V            Print version information
At most one of -f, -d, -p or -e should be used
/ # /usr/bin/sshpass anyinput
sshpass: Failed to run command: No such file or directory
```

It's worth mentioning that the underlying ssh executable works and I can connect to the host that way.

Comment: what's the output of `sshpass ls`?

Comment: `$ docker run -it --rm williamyeh/ansible:alpine3 sshpass ls`

    bin    etc    lib    mnt    root   sbin   sys    usr
    dev    home   media  proc   run    srv    tmp    var

Comment: so it's working fine.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

SSHpass was working fine, but the alpine container python:3.6-alpine doesn't have openssh installed.

This errormessage is confusing as it doesn't mention that the ssh component is failing.

This can be fixed by running `apk add --update openssh`.

This was resolved by changing the line in the Dockerfile from `RUN apk add --update --no-cache sshpass` to `RUN apk add --update --no-cache openssh sshpass`.

Answer (score 1):

`No such file or directory` refers to `hi` and `anyinput` :)

I just installed sshpass on an alpine virtual machine and

```
# sshpass -p <my password> ssh 127.0.0.1
```

works as expected.

**PS**: I am sure you know what you are doing and stuff, but *please* make sure you have looked into public key authentication before reaching for things like `sshpass`.